# Naming element in rbind/list by referencing element from a character vector in R

Tags: r

I have a function that is calculating slopes for multiple variables in a dataframe, for each level of a categorical variable.  I want to summarize the results of a loop within the function, using `rbind`/lists. The issue arises because the treatment levels may not always be the same for each dataframe run through the function.

```
# treatment levels for the dataframe
lvls <- df$treatment

[1] '0.3', '0.9', '2.7', 'N'
```

After a loop I will have 4 slopes from one variable that I want summarized.  They are in a vector that is in the order of the treatment levels.

```
#Slopes will be estimated and saved in a vector after a loop
slope_vec

[1] 0.6548, 0.8749, 0.2938, 0.2384


#Make a summary of the slopes that will later go in a list
slope_summary <- rbind ( c ( '0.3' = slope_vec[1], '0.9' = slope_vec[2], '2.7' = slope_vec[3], 'N' = slope_vec[4] ) )
```

But I want this to be more fluid, since the treatment levels may not always be the same.  What I'm looking for is some way to reference the `lvls` character vector to name the items in `rbind` (and this issue would work for list naming as well) Something like...

```
slope_summary <- rbind ( c ( lvls[1] = slope_vec[1], lvls[2] = slope_vec[2], lvls[3] = slope_vec[3], lvls[4] = slope_vec[4] ) )
```

Comment: I am not sure if I get the issue correctly. Do you intend to `rbind` many vectors with each having different names for its elements?

Comment: No  I want to name things within rbind or a list by referencing a character string from a vector.  I get that in this particular example, that is not necessary, there are simpler ways to give names to the rbind items.  The question is more, is this something that is possible to do?  Can you name things in rbind or list by referencing a vector?  I'm leaning towards no but I'm confused as to why.  lvls[1] is '0.3', so why doesn't lvls[1] = slope_vec[1] work but '0.3' = slope_vec[1] does. Is there a way to get around this?

Comment: Actually I'm wondering about that, too.. I found NOTHING about the matter. I'm considering to open a question myself xD

Comment: There it is: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54762963/why-cant-i-name-vector-elements-inside-c-with-tags-indexed-from-other-variabl

Comment: Awesome! I'll keep an eye on that page too.