# Why can't I name vector elements inside c() with tags indexed from other variable?

Tags: r, vector, naming

When I name the elements of a vector I use tag - value pairs like these:

```
myvec <- c("name1" = 1, "name2" = 2, "name3" = 3)

> myvec
name1 name2 name3 
    1     2     3
```

When I create a vector containing the names and index this vector from inside the c()-function, it doesn't work.

```
namevec <- c("name1", "name2", "name3")

myvec <- c(namevec[1] = 1, namevec[2] = 2, namevec[3] = 3)
Error: unexpected '=' in "myvec <- c(namevec[1] ="
```

My Question now: Why is that? Why does it work if I write `"name1"`, but if I use `namevec[1]`, which returns `"name1"`, it throws an error?

Note: I am not asking for a workaround.There are plenty, such as:

```
"names<-"(c(1,2,3), namevec)
name1 name2 name3 
    1     2     3

setNames(c(1,2,3), namevec)
name1 name2 name3 
    1     2     3

structure(c(1,2,3), .Names = namevec)
name1 name2 name3 
    1     2     3
```

and some more.

I was inspired by this question from a few days ago:

[Naming element in rbind/list by referencing element from a character vector in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54737221/naming-element-in-rbind-list-by-referencing-element-from-a-character-vector-in-r?noredirect=1#comment96297321_54737221)

Comment: I believe it's because you are calling a *function* with *named* arguments. `c` is a simple function, and the named element part is simply a named argument. And in R, you can either have positional or literal named arguments. So that is why you cannot use a variable value as place-in for the name. (There are however workarounds for calling a function with variable named arguments, see `do.call`.)

Comment: To add to that note that when naming the values you don't need to use quotes. You could do c(a=3,b=2)

Comment: Thank you for your comment. What does "literal" mean though? I always thought a literal is everything contained within quotes. Why does it matter how I pass this literal to the function?

Comment: @MrGumble, post as answer?

Comment: Yes, I get the idea but something's missing. I just don't comprehend this leap: *either positional or literal named arguments* ***ergo*** *no variable value*. Because with `c()`the name doesn't exist before I think of one and pass it to the function. Why does it have to be typed?